# Jmeter load test design for workflow

Tags: performance, jmeter

1. I have an api (consider it as parent api) and now the api will give me some children list under it .

ex: parent api (id:1924) , now under parent child ids  are 1,2,3,4

2. Now each child should execute sequential workflow. (This workflow , i created a thread group)
3. Problem is parent api gives me list of children details and children should execute the workflow , how to parallelize childen workflows.
4. children for each parent api might not be sameit may be 1or 2 or upto 1000

To be more clear:

parent gives me child1,child2,child3

child 1 , child2,child3 should execute workflow threadgroup

but all childs should spawn parallelly .

```
                  parent
                     !
    child1.  child2.  child3 child4
      wf       wf       wf     wf
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [Parallel Sampler](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller) plugin for JMeter which executes URLs listed in it in parallel, the list of URLs can be populated dynamically using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and simple [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) code like:

```
1.upto(vars.get('yourVar_matchNr') as int, { index ->
    sampler.addURL(vars.get('yourVar_' + index))
})
```

Parallel Sampler and Controller can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)